# need a really simple WIFE example

Tags: java

Can someone just show me a complete simple java program to 
read in 1 swift message, parse it, and display it? I want to see how to set things up,
step by step. The current documentation is exhaustive but useless, its all fragmented.

Comment: *expected some other type of question when he clicked.. back button*

Comment: Cant stop laughing, the way people have started naming the tools. cucumber, wife?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused -- the documentation contains [this page](http://wife.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=parser), which includes what you (seem) to be looking for, an example of a parse call followed by examples of how you then display the components of the parsed message.

The only part that's not included is how to read the SWIFT message into the variable, and I'd imagine that that depends entirely on how the message is getting to you -- in a file, over a wire, etc. all would need different methods of reading the message.